# Clementine tracks not dragging in playlist

Tags: clementine, playlists

I just upgraded to 11.10 with Unity.

For some reason, when I try to drag a track to change the order, the cursor turns to a no sign and won't let me move the track.

This happens when dragging from my collection to the playlist area as well, unless I put it in the beginning of the playlist. Is this a unity thing? Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @coversnail: I'm not so sure it's a valid bug. I've got the same issue, but in checking with others running the same version - the problem does not occur - so it seems to have something do with our specific systems.